# Show that a lower semi continuous function composed with a continuous function is lower semi continuous

Tags: real-analysis, function-and-relation-composition, semicontinuous-functions

Let $f_1$ and $f_2$ be two functions from $\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$. Furthermore, let $f_1$ be lower semi continuous and $f_2$ be continuous. Show that $f_1\circ f_2$ is lower semi continuous.

Here is my attempt at a solution:

Recall that a function $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ is lower semi continuous (LSC) if the set $\{x\in\mathbb{R} : f(x) > a\}$ is open $\forall a\in\mathbb{R}$. So, let $a\in\mathbb{R}$ and consider the set $U_a = \{x\in\mathbb{R} : f_1\circ f_2(x) > a\}$. Then we can also characterize $U_a$ as the pre-image, $U_a = (f_2^{-1}\circ f_1^{-1})(]a,\infty[)$. Since $f_1$ is LSC, we have that $f_1^{-1}(]a,\infty[)$ must be an open set in $\mathbb{R}$. Then, since $f_2$ is assumed to be continuous, the pre-image of the open set $f_1^{-1}(]a,\infty[)$ under $f_2$ must also be open. Then, since $a$ was an arbitrary element in $\mathbb{R}$, we have $(f_2^{-1}\circ f_1^{-1})(]a,\infty[)$ is open $\forall a\in\mathbb{R}$. Thus $f_1\circ f_2$ is LSC.

In the text I am reading, however, it is not given that $f$ is LSC $\iff$ the set $\{x\in\mathbb{R} : f(x) > a\}$ is open $\forall a\in\mathbb{R}$, this was something I learned in a course last year. Instead, we are given that $f$ is LSC at a point $x$ $\iff$ for every net $(x_a)_{a\in A}$ in $\mathbb{R}$, $x_a\rightarrow x \implies f(x)\leq \lim\inf(x_a)$. I am quite unfamiliar with nets, can someone give me a hint on how to show that these definitions of LSC are equivalent?

Comment: Since the domain of the function in question is first countable, you can replace "net" with "sequence". If the unfamiliarity with nets is the only problem, that could help. Have you an idea how to argue for sequences?

Comment: Yes, with sequences I can show this and I know that in the case of first countable topological spaces a sequence 'captures' the same information as a net. But, using nets, rather than replacing them with sequences, requires a bit more sophisticiation because of the subtelty involved in subnets, no?

Comment: For this proof, the subtleties of subnets play no role, since we're only looking at nets converging to $x$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's also state a localised version of lower semicontinuity in terms of neighbourhoods:

**Definition:** Let $X$ a topological space, and $f \colon X \to \mathbb{R}$ a function. Then $f$ is lower semicontinuous at $x$ if for every $a < f(x)$ the set $f^{-1}(]a,+\infty[)$ is a neighbourhood of $x$.

Then we can show that a function $f \colon X \to \mathbb{R}$ satisfies "$f^{-1}(],a+\infty[)$ is open for every $a \in \mathbb{R}$" if and only if it is lower semicontinuous at $x$ (in the sense of the definition above) for every $x\in X$.

For, if $f^{-1}(]a,+\infty[)$ is open, and $a < f(x)$, then $f^{-1}(]a,+\infty[)$ is a neighbourhood of $x$. And conversely, if $f$ is LSC at every $x$, then $f^{-1}(]a,+\infty[)$ is a neighbourhood of every $x\in X$ with $f(x) > a$ - but that is exactly $f^{-1}(]a,+\infty[)$, which thus is open.

Then we need to see that the two pointwise definitions are equivalent. If $(x_{\alpha})$ is a net converging to $x$, and $a < f(x)$, then there is an $\alpha_0$ such that $x_{\alpha} \in f^{-1}(]a,+\infty[)$ for all $\alpha \geqslant \alpha_0$, since $f^{-1}(]a,+\infty[)$ is a neighbourhood of $x$. Hence $\liminf f(x_{\alpha}) \geqslant a$. Since that holds for every $a < f(x)$, it follows that $\liminf f(x_{\alpha}) \geqslant f(x)$.

Conversely, if $f$ is not lower semicontinuous at $x$ in the sense of the definition above, there is an $a < f(x)$ such that $f^{-1}(]a,+\infty[)$ is not a neighbourhood of $x$. Hence for every neighbourhood $U$ of $x$ we can choose a point $x_U \in U \setminus f^{-1}(]a,+\infty[)$. The family of neighbourhoods of $x$ is a directed set if (partially) ordered by reversed inclusion (i.e. $U \leqslant V \iff V \subset U$), and thus we have a net $(x_U)$ converging to $x$. But by construction, $f(x_U) \leqslant a$ for all $U$, so $\liminf f(x_U) \leqslant a$, so $f$ is also not LSC at $x$ in the sense of the net-definition.